# С помощью каких библиотек можно в Java сделать крутой интерфейс?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Смотрю на разные библиотеки вроде Swing, AWT, javaFX. Такое чувство, что сделаны они для бухгалтерских программ.

И если не Java, то какой язык программированиия стоит изучать ради этих задач? И как совместить тогда Java и сторонний язык программирования?

Comment: На данный момент ничего эффективнее в плане кастомизации и красивее C# + WPF + Expression Studio(Blend+Design) я не видел. Насколько я знаю из всех наиболее близок к нему JavaFX по возможности кастомизации.

Comment: А как совместить в одном проекте основу приложения, которая написана на джаве и gui, написанный на c#

Comment: @ArtemZaichikov: А почему бы не переписать код на C#? Языки достаточно близкие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для `Java` есть неплохие скины (*Look & Feel - LaF*).

На [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/alee/blog/117430/) была статья со списком LaF-стилей для `Java`, лично мне полюбился оттуда [Tiny LaF](http://www.muntjak.de/hans/java/tinylaf/index.html), который меняет стиль программы всего в пару строчек (естественно, предварительно скачав небольшую библиотеку и закинув её в проект):

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.muntjak.tinylookandfeel.TinyLookAndFeel");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Туториал с [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html).

---

Также есть стили для `JavaFX`, например, [вот тут](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/01/this-is-for-the-native-ones/) есть нативные стили.

Популярна также **[Modena](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/)**:

[image: Modena]

Есть также стиль под Mac OS X: [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com/documentation.html), но ее строго рекомендуют использовать под Mac OS, потому что некоторые фишки работают только на Mac OS:

[image: AquaFX]